# python - discord.py sends to many messages

Tags: python, discord, client, discord.py

I am building a discord bot and I set it to respond to messages that include '_hello', but as a response it sends from 1 to 3 messages which are always the same.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '_hello' in message.content.lower():
        print('message received')
        words = message.content.split(' ')
        if len(words) < 3:
            await message.channel.send('incorect syntax')
        else:
            name = words[1]
            userMessage = ""
            for word in words[2:]:
                userMessage = userMessage + word + ' '

            await message.channel.send('hello: ' + name + "\nwith message: " + userMessage)
```

Comment: When you do `message = ""` in your `else` you overwrite the variable that you need to use to send back the message using `await message.channel.send` could it be the issue ?

Comment: oh did not see that thank you :) I fixed it, but it still does not work.

Comment: Confirming this issue. Seems like an API issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause to this issue can be due to accidently running the bot multiple times. This is a glitch that can occur on some IDE's like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) if you close the application while your bot is running. This happens to me sometimes and the only fix I really found that works is changing your bot's token in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/783463225915342903/information) and putting the new token in your run line. All though this is annoying this is due to the bot being run multiple times, and if you close the application while it happened, you can not end the code after you closed the application.

Have a great day! If this doesn't work you can contact me on [discord](https://discord.com/app) at `killrebeest#7187` or reply to this answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen when the program is running multiple times. Check your task manager and check that you only have one python program running

Comment: I did not find the program running in the task manager, however it seems that changing the token fixes the problem.